# Docker - Alpine Elixir container has unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: docker, elixir, alpine-linux, semaphore-ci

I have this [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/MarbilleJuntado/e7fb15bf35d28fbcdd48481e6e9d052a) for my Phoenix application. When running a promotion with Semaphore CI, my deployment fails and returns this error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libssl1.0 (missing):
    required by: world[libssl1.0]
  pdftk (missing):
    required by: world[pdftk]
```

How come it can't fetch these two packages?

Comment: can you post your log?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `erlang:20-alpine` image ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/erlang/docker-erlang-otp/blob/master/20/alpine/Dockerfile)), which is used as base for `elixir:1.6.6-alpine` ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/c0b/docker-elixir/blob/0936291249c7e11d4618a17a2b452045c9e6233a/1.6/alpine/Dockerfile)), has been recently updated from Alpine 3.8 to 3.9 ([Github commit](https://github.com/erlang/docker-erlang-otp/commit/46742a8f2df1db797c56bcf9846af35122552bc7#diff-0498404ad1c8f2ef0bfd27330beec05b)).

The following has changed between Alpine 3.8 and 3.9:

- The `libssl1.0` package has been removed, and superseded by [`libssl1.1`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/x86_64/libssl1.1).
- The [`pdftk`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/pdftk) package has been removed in 3.9, and is only available in the `edge` branch `community` repository (and older Alpine branches).

**libssl:**

This one is easily fixed: just replace the `libssl1.0` package with `libssl1.1`.

**pdftk:**

`pdftk` is more problematic. It depends on `libgcj6`, the Java runtime for GCC 6. 
However, the Java runtime was completely removed from GCC 8 and onwards. `libgcj6` is the Java runtime for GCC 6, and is not compatible with GCC 8. Installing `libgcj6` also pulls the GCC 6 C++ runtime, `libstdc++6 (6.4.0-r9)`.

An attempt to install `pdftk` along with `libgcj6`, for example:

`RUN apk add --no-cache libgcj6 pdftk --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community`

Fails with:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  so:libgcj.so.17 (missing):
    required by: pdftk-2.02-r1[so:libgcj.so.17]
```

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with a workaround, currently.

There's an active open Alpine ticket for this issue: https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/10136, so it's worth keeping an eye for possible updates.

Comment: How do I use 3.8 instead of 3.9?

Comment: @Bargain23 I suspect you can't, without creating your own customized images, since `erlang:20-alpine` was updated in place, and it looks like there's only one `alpine` image variant.